# Associative arrays in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, associative-array

Associative Arrays  as i understood it stores key value pairs and it is of variable length. Like we can add any number of key value pairs to Associative array.

Also i read to use
while loop to traverse sparese Associative array  and
For loop to traverse Dense Associative array.

How can an associative array be sparse it is dynamic and we are adding values to it

Comment: Are you asking about associative arrays in a stored procedure?

Comment: I'm asking about Associative arrays which comes under Collection in Oracle and is defined with following syntax -----------------------------  TYPE sum_multiples IS TABLE OF PLS_INTEGER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER

Comment: This talk is about Python but the explanation of the dict data type will tell you a lot about how associative arrays work internally: http://blip.tv/pycon-us-videos-2009-2010-2011/pycon-2010-the-mighty-dictionary-55-3352147

Answer (score 1):

Associative arrays are sparse because they are stored in the order of the hash of their key and not in the order they were inserted. An array is dense because elements are always appended to the end as they are added. When you preform operations like insert on an array you are actually creating a new array and appending values. This makes inserts "expensive" in that they require more CPU time to find the insertion point and more memory to store the intermediate copies while insertion is taking place.  With an assocative array insertion (as long as it doesnt expand the size of the associative array beyond the hash key size) is fast in that it takes a predictably small amount of CPU and memory. The other thing that is expensive with arrays is looking up a specific value by its key. With associative arrays you can quickly lookup any element (or know immediately that there is no element with that key) while with an array you have to test every index to know where or if an element exists. On small sets this might not seem like a big deal but these problems only get worse the larger your sets become. Don't think associative arrays are the best and only way though. They get their speed by using more memory. Also iterating over all keys in an associative array (depending on the data type implementation) can be slower than iterative through a dense array. As is always the best advice try to choose the best tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

Associative array are dense and sparse depending how you index it.

If you index it with a primary key or pls_integer or something which can pack data densely then the assosiative array becomes dense. And it will be fast to fetch data.

Where as if you index by some varchar2 column or others which wont be easy to fetch then that specific assosiative array is sparse.

Comment: 1. If it wont be easy to fetch then is it sparse ???????
2. Is there no possibility of packing varchar2 indexed array densly ?

Comment: It depends on data. Varchar2 can be dense as well. But most of the time it will be sparse. It completely depends on data you store in the array.